# How to centre-align 'n' number of images, coming from database

Tags: php, html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have links of images stored in database,I want to bring the **set** of images at the centre of the screen (*which in my case is left-aligned*). No matter how many pictures comes dynamically, **the set of the images should be aligned centre**.
Iam using **bootstrap** for designing and here is how my code look like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <?php
         foreach($n as $val)
         {                     // loop to iterate 'n' image links
      ?>
             <div class="col-md-1">
                  <img src="<?php echo $val; ?>" // images showing up.
             </div>
       <?php  
          }
       ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am adding an image below to demonstrate the situation.
[image]
**I have tried the following:**

1. bootstrap classes : center-block (which is based on margin)
2. bootstrap classes : text-center (which is based on text-align)
3. bootstrap classes : "img-responsive center-block"

**Please Note:**

> **I don't want to push the content toward centre forcefully** (like using of bootstrap class "col-md-push-3" or something as such, because the number of images to be displayed is not fixed. They vary time to time)

Comment: you can use specific width and then margin : 0 auto;

Comment: Please try  class="img-responsive center-block"   in <img> tag for image center...

Comment: yes I tried that too, (have mentioned it) but not working.

Comment: have tried "img-responsive center-block" too @Dhaval Patel still not working.

Comment: can you please share here some sample HTML code?

Comment: Yes I did, its in the question : My code is in local machine so cant share link.@DhavalPatel

Comment: Try adding the class `col-md-offset-4` to the first `col-md-1` DIV

Comment: You could dynamically change the push number based on the number of images. this can be done server side - or with JavaScript if you're doing something ajaxy

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. The problem is solved. https://jsfiddle.net/eu2jwmj4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column classes you are using to wrap the images [col-md-1]are floated left by default....you'd have to override that behaviour.

```
.text-center .col-md-1 {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.text-center .col-md-1 {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-100-100-6.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-100-100-6.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-100-100-6.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use some good old CSS using FlexBox, as shown on this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3e4z1cwL/). Basically, it uses a structure like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="picture">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-200-200-1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And then, with some FlexBox properties, you can achieve what you want:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
}

.picture {
   flex: 1 1;
   width: 100%;
}

img {
   width: 100%;
}
```

To sum up, you put the container in flex mode, and then all its div would occupy same space. Some intermediary divs are required in order to keep the aspect ratio of each image.

If you want to center them in case of you have less pictures available, you can still use the `justify-content: center;` property, setting a maximum width on the divs, such as this [other Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eu2jwmj4/).

Note however that this solution [would not work on IE9-](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

Comment: Thank you for the help sir. Your https://jsfiddle.net/eu2jwmj4/ solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make a div with text-align:center 
Amand then make a div inside it with display:inline-block